# R Generating values based on comparison of previous columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I'm hoping to generate a column (Min) that finds the minimum of selected name columns and extract the name of the column as its value. Following is the sample dataframe:

```
          Amy  Abe  Donna  Racheal  Mike     Min       u
          5    34    54     56       23      Amy       0
          43   11    3      33       21      Donna     1
          54   32    21     54       1       Mike      1 
          21   5     43     32       21      Abe       1
          32   21    23     5        32      Racheal   0
          43   2     2      13       45      Abe Donna 1
                            .
                            .
                            .
```

Column u is just a column that is at the end of the dataset. The dataset is rather large therefore I'm trying to find an efficient method to generate column Min.

The code I have on mind:

```
     MinData <- Data %>% mutate(Min = 
     min(colnames(Data)[1:5]))
```

This only extracts name of the columns. What should I add to enable the column to compare values in each row and select the column name with the minimum value?

Comment: What would happen in the event of a tie (same value for `Min` in 2 or more columns) ?

Comment: @neilfws Could we extract the combo of column name for a tie, such as "Amy Mike" as a single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the apply function with which :)

Set up our vector of names

```
person_names= names(df[,1:5]) #Presumably the column names are the names
```

The `1:5` is just there in case you have other columns in your dataset you don't want considered for the minimum check.

Now we can use apply on a custom function which return a name from whichever column has the lowest value for each row.

```
df$Min <- apply(df[,1:5], 1, function(x){person_names[which.min(x)]})
```

Our custom function is as I described already, apply simply applies the function to each column or row of a data-frame or matrix. The second argument `1` indicates rows, if we wanted columns we could change that to a `2`.

`which.min` just returns the element number of wherever the minimum is. `person_names` have our names in order, and `which.min` returns a number which indicates which name has the smallest value.

You could compress this all down into a one-line solution if you wanted to do away with the `person_names` variable.

```
df$Min <- apply(df[,1:5], 1, function(x){names(df[,1:5])[which.min(x)]})
```

If you only have the 5 name columns, drop the `1:5`, if you have columns wherever, just replace that with a vector of your column names or numbers.

**EDIT:** I saw your comment on the other answer. To accommodate for ties, I'll change the custom function so that it checks for all matches with the minimum value of x, then pastes them together with some custom separator. I'll also modify your data so Donna and Racheal tie in the second row.

```
df <- read.table(text = 'Amy  Abe  Donna  Racheal  Mike     Min       u
      5    34    54     56       23      Amy       0
       43   11    3      3       21      Donna     1
       54   32    21     54       1       Mike      1 
       21   5     43     32       21      Abe       1
       32   21    23     5        32      Racheal   0', header = T)

person_names <- names(df[,1:5])

df$Min <- apply(df[,1:5], 1, function(x){paste(person_names[x == min(x)], 
collapse = ", ")})

> df
  Amy Abe Donna Racheal Mike            Min u
1   5  34    54      56   23            Amy 0
2  43  11     3       3   21 Donna, Racheal 1
3  54  32    21      54    1           Mike 1
4  21   5    43      32   21            Abe 1
5  32  21    23       5   32        Racheal 0
```

I've set the `collapse` argument to ", ", which is the separator I've arbitrarily chosen. You could adjust this to just be a space " ", or a semi-colon, or whatever you wanted.

Again, that can be compressed to a one line answer by getting rid of the separate line for `person_names`.

Comment: Could we account for a tie? I have edited my post for such case. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Saw you comment on the other suggested answer and added a 'tied' version :)

Answer (score 3):

Your original data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Amy = c(5L, 43L, 54L, 21L, 32L, 43L), 
                      Abe = c(34L, 11L, 32L, 5L, 21L, 2L), 
                      Donna = c(54L, 3L, 21L, 43L, 23L, 2L), 
                      Racheal = c(56L, 33L, 54L, 32L, 5L, 13L), 
                      Mike = c(23L, 21L, 1L, 21L, 32L, 45L), 
                      u = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)), 
                      row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                      class = "data.frame")
```

We can use `tidyr` and `dplyr` to convert from wide to long, do the calculations and aggregations, then stick it all back together at the end.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  gather(name, value, -u) %>%                      # convert from wide to long
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(idx = row_number()) %>%                   # add a grouping variable
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(idx) %>% 
  mutate(Min = min(value)) %>%                     # calculate min per group (= per row)
  filter(value == Min) %>%                         # keep names with value = Min
  arrange(idx) %>%                                 # order rows as original data
  select(idx, Min = name) %>% 
  summarise(Min = paste(Min, collapse = ",")) %>%  # combine names where Min tied
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Min) %>% 
  bind_cols(df1, .)                                # combine column Min (names) with 
                                                   # original data

  Amy Abe Donna Racheal Mike u       Min
1   5  34    54      56   23 0       Amy
2  43  11     3      33   21 1     Donna
3  54  32    21      54    1 1      Mike
4  21   5    43      32   21 1       Abe
5  32  21    23       5   32 0   Racheal
6  43   2     2      13   45 1 Abe,Donna
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing this conversion vs just applying the function to rows?

Comment: There are pros and cons to most things. I'd guess this could be slower than row-wise for large datasets. On the other hand you could make the case that tidy, long-format data - each column a variable (name, value), each row an observation - has advantages in doing the calculation and subsequent operations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would approach this:

```
library(tidyverse) # we use dplyr and tidyr
Data <- Data %>% 
  mutate(row = 1:length(u)) 

MinData <- Data %>% 
  gather(name, score, -u, -row, -Min) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarize(Min2 = paste(name[score == min(score)], collapse = " ")) %>% # called "Min2" to differentiate it from the "Min" column provided in the example.
  left_join(df %>% mutate(row = 1:length(u)), .)
```

Comment: Could we account for a tie? In such case, the value will be a combination of column names such as "Amy Mike" if Amy = Mike?

Comment: It should handle ties now